# PHP cant get passed on question mark on clean url

Tags: php, html

I need some help with my code as I have got a problem with get pass on the if statement. I am working on the clean url to create a function like `create_newsletter.php?template=new` when I am on the same page.

When I try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    sleep(2)
    header("Location: http://example.com/newsletters/create_newsletter.php?template=new");

    if(isset($_GET['template'])
    {
        echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
    }
}
```

It will not get pass on this line:

```
if(isset($_GET['template'])
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

$template = "";

if(isset($_GET['template']))
{
    $template = $_GET['template'];
}


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    sleep(2)
    $messagename = $_POST['messagename'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    header("Location: http://example.com/newsletters/create_newsletter.php?template=new");

    if(isset($_GET['template'])
    {
        echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
    }
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="messagename" value="">
    <input type="text" name="subject" value="">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next Step">
</form>
```

I have got no idea how I can get pass on the if statement when I am using `header("Location:)`. I have also tried `if ($template)` but it doesn't get pass.

What I am trying to do is to connect to my php page `create_newsletter.php`. I want to input my full name the textbox called `messagename` and input the subject in the `subject` textbox then click on a button. When I click on a button, I want to redirect to `create_newsletter.php?template=new` as I want to disable on two textbox controls `messagename` and `subject`then add the iframe to allow me to get access to another php page so I could write the newsletter in the middle of the screen.

Can you please show me an example what is the best way forward that I could use to get pass on the if statement when I click on a submit button to redirect me to `create_newsletter.php?template=new` so I could disable these controls and add the iframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `if(isset($_GET['template'])` inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition, but the redirect doesn't send a post request.

This should work:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    sleep(2)
    $messagename = $_POST['messagename'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    header("Location: http://example.com/newsletters/create_newsletter.php?template=new");

}

if(isset($_GET['template'])
{
    echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
}
```

But if you need to make a POST request in the redirect, you would need to print a `<form>` and submit it in the client side, or use $_SESSION in the example bellow:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    sleep(2)
    $_SESSION['messagename'] = $_POST['messagename'];
    $_SESSION['subject'] = $_POST['subject'];
    header("Location: http://example.com/newsletters/create_newsletter.php?template=new");

}

if(isset($_GET['template'])
{
    // $_SESSION['messagename'] and $_SESSION['subject'] are available here
    echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but I have got a problem with the variables `$messagename` and `$subject` under the `if(isset($_GET['template'])` because the strings will show as empty but when I use them under the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` it will show the strings. Any idea?

Comment: Since those strings are submitted via POST, they won't show in the second request. Your header just redirects the user to another URL, it doesn't perform a POST request to that url. The only way to propagate those other variables via POST is to submit them in an html form in the client side.

Alternatively, you can store them in a `$_SESSION` so that they become available in future requests.

Comment: @RobertJones check my post for how to accomplish it

Comment: @EnricoDias Oh right, can you show me an example what I could use for those variables via post when I click on a submit?

Comment: To pass via post it would be complicated, you will need to print html tags for a new `<form>`, the values on the inputs and the javascript to auto submit the form. It's not a pretty solution. I updated my answers with an example using $_SESSION.

Comment: @EnricoDias Thank you very much for this. Problem are now resolved! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`, you are redirecting before you can reach the `if(isset($_GET['template'])`.

But I am assuming you would expect this to run because `$_GET['template']` will be set. Although, the problem with your code is that when you redirect, `$_POST['submit']` will **not** be set, therefor it will not execute anything in the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` block, including `if(isset($_GET['template'])`.
This is because a POST request is not persistant, and will not remain if you reload, or redirect

You should consider the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    sleep(2)
    $messagename = $_POST['messagename'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    header("Location: http://example.com/newsletters/create_newsletter.php?template=new");

}

if(isset($_GET['template'])
{
    echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
}
?>
```

---

## Accessing the $messagename and $subject in the if(isset($_GET['template'])


If you want to access the `$messagename` and `$subject` in the `if(isset($_GET['template'])`, you can pass them in the URL. Because when you redirect, no `$_POST` variables will be set, they will go away. You can accomplish this by doing:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    sleep(2)
    $messagename = $_POST['messagename'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    header("Location: http://example.com/newsletters/create_newsletter.php?template=new&messagename=".$messagename."&subject=".$subject);

}

if(isset($_GET['template'])
{
    $messagename = $_GET['messagename'];
    $subject = $_GET['subject'];
    echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the OP's code which unfortunately the officially accepted answer reflects as well.  A semi-colon needs to be appended to the statement that uses sleep() and an extra parenthesis is needed in the statement that tests for $_GET['template'].

In truth, one does not need to complicate the code with signal processing offered by [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)() in order to delay submission of the POSTed data just to determine the value of $_GET['template'].  One could omit sleep() and alter the the code slightly, as follows:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $mess = htmlentities($_POST['mess']);
    $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']);
    header("Location: http://localhost/exp/create_newsletter.php?template=new");
    exit;
}
else
if( isset( $_GET['template']))
{
    echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
    exit;
}
```

Also, instead of using $_GET another alternative is to use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], as follows:

```
<?php
$qs = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PHP_URL_QUERY);

if( $qs == 'template=new' ){
    $template = split("=",$qs)[1];
    echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
    exit;
}
else
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    sleep(2);
    $mess = htmlentities($_POST['mess']);
    $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']);
    header("Location: http://localhost/exp/create_newsletter.php?template=new");
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="mess" value="">
    <input type="text" name="subject" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next Step">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The component parameter of [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) enables this function to return the query string.  One may also opt instead to employ [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str), as follows:

```
<?php
$queries = "";
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queries);

if( isset($queries['template']) && ($queries['template'] == 'new'))
{
    $template = $queries;
    echo "hello robert now you are working on the template";
    exit;
}
else
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    sleep(2);
    $mess = htmlentities($_POST['mess']);
    $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']);
    header("Location: http://localhost/exp/create_newsletter.php?template=new");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Note: it is very important to always treat data from a POST or GET as tainted instead of directly assigning the data to a variable and using that variable.  Using [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)() is one way to attempt to prevent  possible security issues.